# Django Rest Framwork CSRF cookie not found for PUT method

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I'm getting started with DRF, I created a class based view for some CRUD operations, so the GET and POST method work fine, however when I try to send a PUT request from Postman, I get the following error :

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /post/1
```

I read that `as_view()` call csrf_exempt internally so it should have exempted the csrf token issue, I also tried with method decorators, however it did not worked as well.

```
urls.py
...
url(r'^post$',PostView.as_view()),
#url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',PostView.as_view()),
...
```

views.py
..

```
#-------- API for CRUD -----------------#
class PostView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self,pk,user_id):
        try:
            return Post.objects.get(pk=pk,user_id=user_id)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self,request):
        post = Post.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
        serializer = PostSerializer(post)
        return Response({"success":True,"data":serializer.data},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        post = self.get_object(pk,request.user.id)
        serializer = PostSerializer(post, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user=request.user.id)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def post(self,request):
        params = request.data
        params['user'] = request.user.id
        serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        saved_data = self.perform_create(serializer)
        post = PostSerializer(saved_data)
        return Response({"success":True, "message":"Post  Added Successfully","data":post.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save()
...
```

Can someone let me know, where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can we get to see your PUT view?

Comment: Sure, I have added the view class

Comment: Something is getting messed with this line             `serializer.save(user=request.user.id)` call simply `serializer.save()` as your are passing above post and request.data in serializer

Comment: That did'nt worked either

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a `ModelViewSet` to see if it works. If it works the problem is with your `class PostView(APIView):`. If it doesn't work the problem would be with some middleware, token, authentication.